# Anchor link function - onclick and href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have anchor link with onclick and href functions. like below code

```
$("div.actions").append('<a id="excelExport" onClick="callajax();" class="actionButton" alt="Export to Excel" title="Export to Excel" href="partexport" ></a>')

function callajax() {
     jQuery.ajax({
     url : '<s:url action="partexport"/>',
     data : "fters.productNbr" : $("#productsTextArea1").val()} });

     }
```

Callajax is not at all calling when click the anchor link.

Comment: Don't add inline event-handlers. you're using jQuery, so use the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click) method.

Comment: Your sample code has multiple syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a coulple things at play here.

1. if you are using jquery already it is best to use jquery to attach the handler. Given this is an injected link it is tricky but my example covers how to do that.
2. Your semi-colon is outside of the quotation marks for the onClick handler
3. To avoid the default behavior of an anchor tag, all e.preventDefault(). This one isn't as big of a deal in your case as you dont redirect to an actual location but you might see odd behavior if you dont explicitly say 'dont do the default behavior'

http://jsfiddle.net/g30rg3/u5k95/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.actions").append('<a id="excelExport" class="actionButton" alt="Export to Excel" title="Export to Excel" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">click me</a>');
    $('div.actions').on('click.mylink', '#excelExport',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        callajax();
    });

});

function callajax() {
    alert('clicked');

}
```

Comment: good example. After alert clicked the flow to open the stackoverflow.com , but its not forwarding ?

Comment: if you do want it to proceed to stackoverflow.com, comment out the 'e.preventDefault();' line

Comment: what does do click.mylink ?

Comment: it is just a click handler. You can tag your handlers to help prevent collisions

Comment: TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
$("div.actions").on('click', '#excelExport',function(e){

Comment: TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function
jQuery("div.actions").on('click', '#excelExport',function(e){

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33508/discussion-between-george-and-user2444474)

Comment: @Georage if i comment preventDefault not at all calling any method.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle and show the behavior you are experiencing?

Comment: try here ---http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/32/ - After click the search button , you can link XLS on top of the table.There only we are trying now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g30rg3/rwPFx/33/ if you update the jquery to 1.7.2 in this jsfiddle all works fine. the on method was not added until 1.7

Answer (score 2):

The `click` handler will fire first. Depending on how to process your click, you can control whether the href link action goes through or not.

You can do both - i.e. have your click handler as well as the link action to go through. All you need to do is not `return false` or call `event.preventDefault()` from your click handler.

Comment: Updated question, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The click event will be executed first and then depending on the result, the href will be executed. For example returning `false` from the click event will prevent the href from being executed.